# Cast, pointers, unsigned, output

Tags: pointers, casting, unsigned

`float f = 010; unsigned *pi = (unsigned *) &f; printf("%x", *pi);`
I don't understand why is output 41000000.

Comment: Assuming this is C (which it looks like, but you didn't tag the language) you are strictly speaking violating strict aliasing and invoking *undefined behavior*. What most compilers will however do is reinterpret the bit representation of the float as an unsigned integer. Understanding the result requires studying how `float`s are represented in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets break this down into individual steps.

```
 float f = 010;
```

this sets f to 8.0 (!) because `010` is in octal.

lets see what gets stored in memory, using my vs debugger I see

[image]

Why, well this is how 8.0 is stored in binary floating point. See https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for a tool which will show you the binary representation of any float. Look here for a definition of the format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format.

next you say

```
float *pf = &f;
```

ok take the address of `f`

```
 unsigned* pi = (unsigned*)pf;
```

now treat the pointer to a float as though it were a pointer to an int. Nothing gets changed in f, we just get a pointer that thinks its pointing at an unsigned (32 bit) integer

```
 unsigned i = *pi;
```

deference that pointer. `i` gets loaded with the four bytes in f.

```
printf("%x", i);
```

print that , in hex, treating those bytes as an int.

so you get 41000000 cos thats what those bytes contain.

check out this for an interesting video that shows this trick in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8u_k2LIZyo